# Dropped parentheses in notation for linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

Why do we often (as in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, p.$~206$) write $A\vec x$ to mean $A(\vec x)$ for linear transformations $A$?

I think it's because we can write $A(\vec x+\vec y)=A\vec x+A\vec y$ and pretend like we have a multiplication that is distributive over addition, which makes thinking about linear transformations easier. My friend insists it's because it simplifies things to identify $A$ with its matrix, and we tend to not write parentheses when multiplying matrices with vectors.

Comment: We do that everywhere, not just in linear algebra. Source: Evan Chen's Infinitely Large Napkin. In the topology section, he mentions writing $fx$ is easier than $f(x)$

Comment: In mathematical writing, as in any kind of writing, clarity of expression is important. It's important, when you are writing mathematics, to think about how clearly you are communicating what you want to say. Sometimes more symbols add clarity, and sometimes instead they subtract clarity, and one should think about the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Rudin, but to me this looks like a writer who is essentially identifying a matrix with a linear transformation

I would write $A\vec{x}$ (to mean a matrix multiplied by a vector) and I would not use parentheses.

Then I usually separately define a linear transformation as $T(\vec{x}) := A\vec{x}$ and then always use parentheses for that, just like any other function (*i.e.* you always write '$f(x)$' ...'$fx$' just looks like nonsense)

Since it's an analysis book this not a big deal. But if you were teaching linear algebra, you'd want to emphasize the distinction

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about identifying linear maps and matrices: not always is a linear map $f(x)$ written with a matrix multiplying from *the left*, for example, $f(x) = xA$, where $x$ and $A$ are matrices of agreeing shapes, is a linear map.